# Notice Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 48

Tags: linux, laravel, vue.js, linux-mint

> **sending data from frontend using vue js and axios request**  image is getting temp memory and the send that notice it happens only in linux

```
  <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" id="coverImage" name="image" ref="files" 
                 @change="uploadCoverImage" class="custom-file-input" multiple/>
                        <label id="coverImageLabel" class="custom-file-label" 
       for="coverImage">Add image</label>
  </div>


 ----------
```

> **method on upload and send image this code is working fine**

```
  uploadCoverImage(event){
         $('#coverImageLabel').text(event.target.files[0].name);
         this.coverImage = event.target.files[0];
   },
    createProduct(){
            //Save product to database
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', this.name);
            formData.append('coverImage',  this.coverImage);
             const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
              }
             axios.post('/product/create', formData, config
             ).then((response)=>{
                var res = response.data;
                if(res.slice(0,6) === '<br />'){
                    this.product_id = res.slice(123, 145);
                }else{
                    this.product_id = response.data;
                }
            })
            .catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e);
            }); 
    },
```

---

> product service

```
       public function create($request){

            $product            = null;
            $user               = Auth::user();

            $data = [
               'name'                       =>  $request->name,
            ]
            if($request->hasFile('coverImage')){
            $data['cover_image'] = $this->ImageService->save_image(
                        $request->coverImage, 
                        FilePath::getProductsDirectoryPath().$brand_slug,
                        'cover_image_'.$seller_id.'_'.$brand_id.'_'.time(),
                        false
                    );
            }
           $product = Product::create($data);
           return $product->id
         }
```

---

image service
public function save_image($image, $folder, $file_name=null, $crop=false){

```
           $destination_path    = public_path($folder);
          $file_new_name        = ($file_name)? ($file_name.'.jpg') : (time().'.jpg');
          $file_path            = $destination_path . '/' . $file_new_name;
          $img                  = Image::make($image)->save($file_path);
          $loc              = $folder.'/'.$file_new_name;

    return $loc;
 }
```

---

```
      //
```

> this is out put but i need only id in response

```
     Notice:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in 
     Unknown on line 0


      48

  //error_reporting(0) and directory permissions not solved
```